# What is the difference beetwen Random Forest and Random Subspace Method?

Tags: random-forest, bootstrap, ensemble-learning

Is the only difference that the Random Forest enforces the use of decision trees as a base learner and use bootstrap sampling?

Answer (score 1):

In [Random subspace method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Random_subspace_method), we subsample the features, and base learners can be anything. In random forests, we subsample the training set, the features and use decision trees as base learners. All of these subsampling are with replacement in both methods.